# UIWebView timeout Problem due to Internet not available?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a login screen in UIWebView.... and suppose i have entered information and click to button in UIWebView and suddenly my Internet goes off... then how to check i dont have Internet.

Actually I am showing Activity Indicator as soon as i clicked to signin button so my UI getting stuck and i am not able to hide indicator.

This delegate is also not getting called if i dont have internet

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Apple provide a substantial sample project that demonstrates how you can use networking classes to detect whether you have internet connectivity - it's a fair bit of code, but it's harder than it looks!

It is very straightforward, and probably encouraged, to integrate Apple's reachability code into your application to check for connectivity.

The sample code can be downloaded here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: i knw that code.. infact i am using it.. my problem is: if i have internet and webview has been loaded.. and on 1 of the UIWebView button clicking action if internet is goes off.. then where i will get notification that there is no internet ? no such webview delegates available also

Answer (score -2):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
       //check internet connection using Reachability class.
}
```

Comment: This case is not possible.... as soon as Internet goes off it will not go in this delegate.